# Buscar número de coincidencias entre listados de strings

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando obtener el número de coincidencias entre varios listados, los valores que he de buscar los recibo siendo `string[]` y luego he de buscar en un `List<List<string>>` el número de coincidencias, lo que estoy realizando para obtener es:

```
//Obtengo de BBDD el listado de Problemas
List<Problema> posiblesProblemas = _svcConfiguracion.GetProblemas();
List<List<string>> Palabras = new List<List<string>>();
        
//Creo el listado con el total de posibles problemas    
foreach(var problema in posiblesProblemas)
{
    Palabras.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(problema.PalabrasClave));
}

//Realizo una pseudoquery para obtener los resultados
var res1 = (from string part in Palabras
            select new
                    {
                        list = part,
                        count = part.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Sum(p => palabrasClave.Contains(p) ? 1 : 0)
                    }).OrderByDescending(p => p.count).First();
```

Pero me esta fallando al obtener los resultados diciendo:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' al tipo
> 'System.String'.'

Se que es por el listado de listados, pero no se cómo aplicar para que lo realice.

Comment: Para que haces List<List<string>> ? no seria lo mismo List<string>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que tu  problema esta  en  el Json, porque tu recibes una columna desde la base de datos lo cual seria un array y los recorres.

Debes cambiar el cast, ya  que tu `var problema` seria un `string`.

```
List<Problema> posiblesProblemas = _svcConfiguracion.GetProblemas();
List<string> Palabras = new List<string>();
        
//Creo el listado con el total de posibles problemas    
foreach(var problema in posiblesProblemas)
{  
    Palabras = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(problema.PalabrasClave);

     //Realizo una pseudoquery para obtener los resultados
var res1 = (from string part in Palabras
            select new
                    {
                        list = part,
                        count = part.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Sum(p => palabrasClave.Contains(p) ? 1 : 0)
                    }).OrderByDescending(p => p.count).First();
}
```

Comment: No me sirve, problema.PalabrasClave es un listado, que pertenece al objeto problema, me falla la deserialización si aplico ese cambio y convierto a un list plano Palabras, aparte perderia el hilo de a que problema tengo que aportarle las coincidencias

Comment: Perdona, si que estabas bien encaminado, pero para funcionar el listado Palabras lo he convertido a plano, dentro del foreach he cambiado el add por una igualdad y he metido la consulta